# Build a binary-heap from an array, which method is more efficient and why

Tags: c, performance, algorithm, binary-heap

I am learning about heaps and i have found two ways of building them from a given array:
I am trying to build up a MAX Heap.

1.Top to down approach

Here i just check for every element if it is at the correct position or not. By using a method called restoreUp, in which every key is compared to its parent key , and if the parent key is smaller than the parent key is moved down.This procedue continues till the parent key is greater.I check it for every key starting at index position 2.

My Code is:

```
void restoreUp(int arr[],int i)
{
    int k=arr[i];
    int par=i/2;
    while(arr[par]<k)
    {
        arr[i]=arr[par];
        i=par;
        par=i/2;
    }
    arr[i]=k;
}
void buildheap1(int arr[],int size)
{
    int i;
    for(i=2;i<=size;i++)
       restoreUp(arr,i);
}
```

1. Bottom up approach

Here i start from the first non leaf node present at index floor(size/2), and call a method restoreDown until node number 1.I compare a key with both its left and right child and then the greater child is moved up.If both children are greater than the key then move the larger of the 2 children up.This procedure stops when both children are smaller than the key.

My Code is:

```
void restoreDown(int arr[],int i,int size)
{
    int left=2*i;
    int right=2*i+1;
    int num=arr[i];
    while(right<=size)
    {
        if(num>arr[left] && num>arr[right])
        {
            arr[i]=num;
            return;
        }
        else if(arr[left]>arr[right])
        {
            arr[i]=arr[left];
            i=left;
        }
        else
        {
            arr[i]=arr[right];
            i=right;
        }
        left=2*i;
        right=2*i+1;
    }
    if(left==size && arr[left]>num)
    {
        arr[i]=arr[left];
        i=left;
    }
    arr[i]=num;
}
void buildheap2(int arr[],int size)
{
    int i;
    for(i=size/2;i>=1;i--)
       restoreDown(arr,i,size);
}
```

Both the methods are working for me. 
I just wanted to know which method is more efficient and why?

Comment: For asymptotic complexity, see [the relevant Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heapsort), starting from *Also, the "siftDown" version of heapify*. For real-life performance, use a profiler.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking with modern CPU (having caches). Reading and array backward is usually a very bad idea as it generates a lot of cache misses. Unless (of course) the array was already in cache.

So first approach seems to be better from that point of view.

Comment: But the first approach is O(n log n), whereas the second approach is O(log n). The added algorithmic complexity of the first is going to dwarf the increased cache miss rate of the second. In addition, although the first approach does iterate over the array in the forward direction, it also references the array backwards when checking the parents. In the same way, the second approach reads the array backwards, but also reads forward when accessing children. I suspect there would be very close to the same number of cache misses per iteration in both approaches.